# magento 2.2 admin redirect loop after using data migration tool

Tags: data-migration, redirect-loop

We have a large Magento 1,9 instance (20 storeviews). Tested the Magento Data Migration Tool successfully with a smaller instance and Magento 2.1. Now testing with the larger instance and finding that after the settings migration the admin area is failing to load, getting stuck in a redirect loop. 
I have tried the suggested fixes from other posts here (use https in adminhtml set to 0 and 1, cookie locations) but no luck so far.
Using Firefox dev edition I can see that the requests are consistently redirecting to the same URL, but with different session keys. Anyone come across this before or have any other suggestions?

Comment: I am having same issue with Magento 2.2.2 after migration. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I did find a solution, or at least a workaround.
I ran a comparison between the pre-migration database and with migrated settings. There are a lot of additional "web" settings in the "core_config_data" table. Removing all but the required settings as per this comparison did the trick.
My thinking is that you can reset these within the admin area for your stores/storeviews and this will keep it "Magento 2 friendly".

Comment: In my case it was caused by cookies. So I changed domain under "core_config_data" table "web/cookie/cookie_domain" path to magento.localhost (Change it to your domain). Its working fine now. Make sure to clear cache.